# How can I make basic text more appealing?

Tags: css, text

For an assignment i have to create a website. I have a homepage where i have a large chunk of text explaining what the business is about etc. Although it is very plain looking. How can I make this plain chunk of text more appealing?

This is my CSS that affects the text.

```
Body{
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px;
letter-spacing: -.5px;
}
```

Comment: "more appealing" is incredibly subjective - I could say that your business copy needs to look professional, but "professional" is still a very vague description.

Comment: add `color:#b4d455` to make it look badass

Comment: Adjust the line height and tweak the letter and word spacing. That always has a dramatic but subtle effect.

Comment: @metacubed: You do realize the way to communicate with mods is not with comments but with flags... in any case I don't think UX accepts questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing what it looks like currently but you could try playing around with:

- Custom fonts with @fontface
  (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)
- Line-height (line-height: 19px)
- Letter-spacing (letter-spacing: 0.5px)
- Text color (color: #000000)
- Text Shadow (text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000)

I personally don't like using text-shadow but depending on what you're trying to achieve it may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could go find a website with text that you find appealing and take a look at their CSS file (press F12 if you're using Chrome). That'll give you an idea of what kinds of fonts, colors, spacing etc. they use.